# How can I query maximum values in records in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get all records in Elasticsearch which matches my criteria which is like the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_x AS px
WHERE version = (
    SELECT MAX(version) FROM table_x
    WHERE type=px.type
) AND title LIKE '%title%'
```

Comment: use aggregation query: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Thanks, but aggregation queries are for stats only! I cannot use its result in my query. Am I wrong?

Comment: you're right! i wasn't paying attention to the query close enough :( not sure if this is possible using one single query.